# Paypal DoDirectPaymentRequest returning NULL

Tags: paypal

I am using Paypal's classic API to do a Direct Payment. Here's the code:

```
        require('merchant-sdk-php-master/samples/PPBootStrap.php');

        $logger = new PPLoggingManager('DoDirectPayment');

        $address = new AddressType();
        $address->Name = $full_name;
        $address->Street1 = $address_1;
        $address->Street2 = $address_2;
        $address->CityName = $city;
        $address->StateOrProvince = $province;
        $address->PostalCode = $postal_code;
        $address->Country = $country;
        $address->Phone = $phone;

        $paymentDetails = new PaymentDetailsType();
        $paymentDetails->ShipToAddress = $address;
        $paymentDetails->OrderTotal = new BasicAmountType('CAD', $amount);

        $personName = new PersonNameType();
        $personName->FirstName = $first_name;
        $personName->LastName = $last_name;

        $payer = new PayerInfoType();
        $payer->PayerName = $personName;
        $payer->Address = $address;
        $payer->PayerCountry = $country;

        $cardDetails = new CreditCardDetailsType();
        $cardDetails->CreditCardNumber = $card_number;
        $cardDetails->CreditCardType = $card_type;
        $cardDetails->ExpMonth = $expiry_month;
        $cardDetails->ExpYear = $expiry_year;
        $cardDetails->CVV2 = $cvv;
        $cardDetails->CardOwner = $payer;

        $ddReqDetails = new DoDirectPaymentRequestDetailsType();
        $ddReqDetails->CreditCard = $cardDetails;
        $ddReqDetails->PaymentDetails = $paymentDetails;
        $ddReqDetails->PaymentAction = 'Sale';
        $ddReqDetails->IPAddress = $ip_address;
        $ddReqDetails->ReturnFMFDetails = true;

        $doDirectPaymentReq = new DoDirectPaymentReq();
        $doDirectPaymentReq->DoDirectPaymentRequest = new DoDirectPaymentRequestType($ddReqDetails);

        $logger->info("created doDirectPaymentReq Object");

        $paypalService = new PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService();

        try{
            $doDirectPaymentResponse = $paypalService->DoDirectPayment($doDirectPaymentReq);
            var_dump($doDirectPaymentResponse);
        } 
        catch (Exception $ex){
            var_dump($ex);
        }
```

This is the object it returns:

```
object(DoDirectPaymentResponseType)#84 (15) { ["Amount"]=> NULL ["AVSCode"]=> NULL ["CVV2Code"]=> NULL ["TransactionID"]=> NULL ["PendingReason"]=> NULL ["PaymentStatus"]=> NULL ["FMFDetails"]=> NULL ["ThreeDSecureResponse"]=> NULL ["PaymentAdviceCode"]=> NULL ["Timestamp"]=> NULL ["Ack"]=> NULL ["CorrelationID"]=> NULL ["Errors"]=> NULL ["Version"]=> NULL ["Build"]=> NULL } ­
```

I'm Canadian so I can't use the new API's because they're not available here yet. I'm stuck with the classic API. Why am I getting this result?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I'd also like to mention that when I remove information that it needs in order to make the request, the response is a failure with error codes and everything, so I am connecting to Paypal.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, yesterday I was getting an object of NULL values. However, today I am getting an error message. I fixed the error and received a success.

Why it was showing me the error message today and not yesterday, I do not know. I never changed any of the code so it must have been something on Paypal's end.

Still have no idea what was wrong, but that's that.